# Terminate thread immediately when some variable set to true

Tags: python, multithreading

how to terminate the thread when some variable value set to true?

```
import threading
class test(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self):
         self.stopThread = False
         self.start():
     def start(self):
         while not self.stopThread:
              callOtherFunction    //which takes alomst 30 sec to execute
     def stop(self):
         self.stopThread = True
```

now the problem is that if the start function is called and while loop started then it will check the stop condition on next iteration, when it completed its internal work, so if the call is made to callOtherFunction then it still waits 30 sec to exit.. i want to immediately terminate the thread when the variable is set. is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: or you should use multiprocessing if you want to kill immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered here:

[Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

The bottom line is that, if you can help it, you should avoid killing a thread this way. However, if you must, there are some tricks you can try.

Also, to be thread-safe, you should make `self.stopThread` a `threading.Event()` and use `set()` and `clear()` to signal when the thread should be stopped.